# Trouble whit installation and importing in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, sis

I'm following a GUI aplication python course. And I can't handle with PyQt4.

I'm at manjaro linux, after some failed attempts, seems I have successfully installed PyQt4 and sis. But now, when trying to import, I can't.

When I run: *import PyQt4* 
Works perfectly.

When I run: *from PyQt4 import **
Same, but I can't use the classes

But, when I run: *from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore*
This doesn't work.

Message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejemplo_GUI.pyw", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui' from 'PyQt4' (unknown location)
```

I attempted to do the istallation process again, but the same error.

Now, I download the data in site-package/PyQt4 from another source and I pasted it into the folder. It raises this errror:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui' from 'PyQt4' (/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.py)
```

Comment: What about from PyQt4.QtGui import <staff>?

Comment: Run `python -v -c "'from PyQt4 import QtGui"` and read the output. There should be information where is problem.

Comment: Why are you using pyqt4? It's been obsolete since 2015. Install the pyqt5 packages provided by manjaro.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that the folder in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt4 it's empty. So for this reason I can immport the pakage but not the data. So I figured out that the problem is at the installation process. I know there are lots of related questions. I have tried all of them, but no one works.

Comment: I'm following a guided book that works on PyQt4.

Comment: @AjapolloTrukatila execute: `sudo pacman -S python-pyqt4`

Comment: @eyllanesc ther's no packet called python-pyqt4